# Return activerecord results for jsonb column array count greater than given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

In my rails 5 application with a Postgresql database,  there is a class `Listing` with a jsonb column `media`.

I want to return the records that have array length greater than 10 in the `media` column.

How would I construct that query in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it is very straightforward

`Listing.where('JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH(media) > 10')`